# Вызов из XAML custom-компонента

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Проблема, При попытке компиляции дает с строке с overlaycanvas ошибку "Класс overlaycanvas не найден."

Вроде в заголовке путь xlmns прописал, в самой строке префикс пути указал. 
В чем загвоздка не пониманию, помогите.

Листинг разметки основной формы

```
<Documentcontext
  xmlns:ctrl = "clr-namespace:Приложение.Интерфейс">
     <ctrl:OverlayCanvas Name="ОбластьДиалога"></ctrl:OverlayCanvas>
</Documentcontext>
```

Листинг компонента, OverlayCanvas.cs (в проекте создал папку интерфейс и внее сохранил компонент)

```
public class OverlayCanvas : Canvas
{
    public DrawingContext Канва
    {
        get
        {
            return MarkerVisual.RenderOpen();
        }
    }

    VisualCollection visuals;
    DrawingVisual MarkerVisual = new DrawingVisual();

    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    {
        return visuals[index];
    }
    protected override int VisualChildrenCount
    {
        get
        {
            return visuals.Count;
        }
    }

    public OverlayCanvas()
    {
        this.AddVisualChild(MarkerVisual);
    }
}
```

Comment: А ваш `OverlayCanvas` находится в той же сборке, или в другой? Если в той же, попробуйте Rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема отпала сама собой. Возможно такое поведение как было у меня связано както с версией среды в которой я работаю (Visual Express 10), а может быть проблема глубже в самой платформе.

При добавлении самописного компонента "OverlayCanvas" в разметку, при выполнении кода система не корректно обрабатывала Exception при обращении к полю visual, так как у меня в этом поле ошибка. А дальше среда делала заключение, что такое компонента нет и красила строку красным.

В случае же когда я добавил компонент в форму через панель компонентов, система нормально обработала exception И даже выдала сообщение, что поле Visual равно null и обратиться к нему не представляется возможным.

После выяснения проблемы. Я исправил код

```
public OverlayCanvas()
{
    this.AddVisualChild(MarkerVisual);
}
```

добавив инициализацию visuals

```
public OverlayCanvas()
{
    visuals = new VisualCollection(this);
    this.AddVisualChild(MarkerVisual);
}
```

После чего стали срабатывать нормально как первый способ, так и второй.